# How to update multiple instances asp.net website

Tags: asp.net

We have a server with IIS which runs about 20 instances of our asp.net website. Whenever I make an update at the moment I have to manually update those instances. This is obviously not scalable.

What are the best practices doing this? I was thinking putting a map on the server and let the other instances watch this map for changes (and copy the latest version if there are any). Would this be enough? Are there build in tools in Windows Server that do something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `WebDeploy`:

[Web Deploy 2.0](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy)

[Centralized Web Farm Management](http://www.iis.net/overview/CentralizedWebFarmManagement)

Comment: Hmmm! I have another question! Hopefully someone can help me.

The server has 20 websites running. All those 20 websites are the same (except for some .config files). Is it possible to sync these with webdeploy? It seems very usefull if I have multiple servers but just for 1 server with multiple sites I can't find that much documentation.